# Trouble installing Magick Rotation

Tags: software-installation

I'm new to Ubuntu and having trouble installing Magick Rotation. I downloaded version 1.6.2 and extracted the archive. But when I want to launch the installer it just opens a text file with a bunch of code. When I click on "Open With" and select "Run Software" it only loads for a few seconds without result. Do I need to install some other software first?

I'm using a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo Yoga 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every normal software has some kind of "install instructions" - did you read that?

**General answer:**
Exactly HOW to install depends on how the software developer has chosen to implement that function.

It might be by use of a package installer like `apt-get`. `synaptic`, (both are front-ends for ubuntu) `rpm` (redhat) or a plethora of others, depending on OS.

It might be a specific software developed in any of the programming langauges available

Or it might be a "bash" or "sh" script (a text file with commands) that you run from a Terminal emulator / Shell prompt.

It may also be a few simple bash commands, that does the trick.

Which style it is, makes the installation be very different depending on that.

**Specific for ubuntu:**
If you can find a Ubuntu specific installation method that involvers apt, apt-get, synaptic, or the Ubuntu software center - prefer that choice, as it normally provides the means to REMOVE the software as easily as it is to install it.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. I managed to manually install the software (I think) by installing some other programs first and following the install instructions, but now I can't run it. It says I have to install "62-magick.rules" in "/etc/udev/rules.d", but the file is already there. Restarting doesn't help.

Comment: I opened the rules file to see if there may be some mistake and it looks like my device is not listed there. In the file are multiple lines that look like this: SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{name}=="some name", MODE="640", GROUP="magick", SYMLINK="input/magick-rotation" where some name is "ThinkPad Extra Buttons" for example. Any idea how I can find out the name for my device? A quick google search left me puzzled.